# After query execution detect that merge created node, not matched

Tags: node.js, neo4j, cypher, node-neo4j

Simple question, that I'm having hard time googling. Using `cypher` via `node-neo4j`, I want to run some logic after query, but only if my `MERGE` created node (i.e `ON CREATE` inside query was triggered), not matched it. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could have `created_at` and `matched_at` fields with `MERGE` and then check them for equality when you return the object:

```
MERGE (f:Foo)
ON CREATE SET f.created_at = timestamp()
ON MATCH SET f.matched_at = timestamp()
RETURN f
```

Comment: so there is no way to have direct feed from db transaction like matched/created count and workaround is to store this useless fields?

Comment: It's a good question.  I don't know of a way, but there might be one.  I would argue that the `created_at` is useless, though.  By default many DB libraries store `created_at` and `updated_at` fields and you generally don't use them at first, but they often come in handy in debugging.

Comment: I was too fast calling them 'useless', yes, on the second thought they may indeed come in handy not only in this case. Thanks for the answer, Brian! Will go after it.

Comment: Cool ;)  I agree it feels like a workaround.  I'd also like a better answer